# Starting an exe in the same console

Tags: batch-file

Quick and simple question: I have a batch file that calls for some .exe like so:

```
START /WAIT GVE %opt%
```

My problem is that the program starts in a new console, is their anyway to make it start in the same console ? I've tried /NOCONSOLE option without success.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just need the `/B` option (assuming the exe is a console app)

```
start "" /b /wait gve %opt%
```